# Slack opening when receiving notifications

Tags: windows-11, slack

How do I prevent Slack from opening up when I receive a notification when it is minimized to the task bar?

Every time a new notification comes in from any channel I am in, Slack comes out of the notification area and the app opens.

It does not become the active application, so that is good, but I'd like to not see it at all, unless I want to open Slack.

**Edit:** I am running on Windows 11. Slack version Production 4.32.122 64-bit.

Comment: Which operating system ?

Comment: I have found [this advice](https://www.reddit.com/r/Slack/comments/5enozl/problem_minimizing_slack_app_to_system_tray_win10/) : "If you set up slack to flash window on notification as "Always" app will stay on taskbar. If you change it to something else it will allow you to close window to system tray." Does it help?

Comment: I don't recall that ever happening in Slack. Apart from system, which version is it and what are your notification settings?

Comment: Apologies. I am running on Windows 11. Slack version Production 4.32.122 64-bit.

Comment: @harrymc, no, unfortuntely not. My Slack is set to "Never" flash window.

Comment: Can you minimize it to the traybar (not the taskbar) ?

Comment: Yes, when minimizing, it goes to the tray. Just not sure why it comes out of the tray in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

It also happens to me.

Here's how I did it:

- Click your avatar on bottom left.
- Click **Preferences**.
- Click **Notifications**.
- Scroll to **Flash window when a notification is received**.
- Select **Never**.

Hope it helps.

[image: Screenshot of the settings]